# Date Validation then subset list of valid dates in Pytho

Tags: python, loops, datetime, boolean, subset

I have a lists of datetime strings, some are valid while some are not (i.e. Feb 30). I would like to remove these invalid dates from my list.
Example code:

```
dates = ["20200101 09:00:00", "20200230 09:15:00", "20200315 15:00:00", "20200732 14:00:00"]
```

I would like to make it so dates would only contain `["20200101 09:00:00",  "20200315 "15:00:00"]` as the other elements are invalid dates.

I have tried the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
for x in dates:
   print(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

On the second iteration it gave me a

```
ValueError : day is out of range for month
```

The idea is to generate a boolean series to subset `dates`. Any ideas of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

They key is to catch and handle the exception that is getting raised for the invalid date strings.  To make your example work:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = ["20200101 09:00:00", "20200230 09:15:00", "20200315 15:00:00", "20200732 14:00:00"]

for x in dates:
  try:
    print(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

To make it a little more useful you could wrap the exception handling in a validator function:

```
def date_str_is_valid(date_str):
  try:
    datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

for x in dates:
  if date_str_is_valid(date_str):
    print(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Note for the above example you are now calling strptime twice for each string, so it isn't the most efficient (you could modify the validator to return the srptime'd value or None)

But, now that you have a validator function, you can use it to filter the list:

```
# Using filter:
>>> list(filter(date_str_is_valid, dates))
['20200101 09:00:00', '20200315 15:00:00']

# Using list comprehension
>>> [d for d in dates if date_str_is_valid(d)]
['20200101 09:00:00', '20200315 15:00:00']
```

> The idea is to generate a boolean series to subset dates.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this.  If you are after a list of True/False values that indicate whether each list element is valid:

```
# Using list comprehension
>>> [date_str_is_valid(x) for x in dates]
[True, False, True, False]

# Using map
>>> list(map(date_str_is_valid, dates))
[True, False, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code, it's in the flawed logic:

You see, for the second string: `"20200230 09:15:00"`, you are asking
for the 30th of Febuary, which, doesn't exist!

Same goes for the last string:
`"20200732 14:00:00"`, where you are asking for the 32nd of July, which, there *is no month* that has 32 days!
If you simply subtract *one* day from the the two flawed strings:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ["20200101 09:00:00", "20200229 09:15:00", "20200315 15:00:00", "20200731 14:00:00"]

for x in dates:
   print(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01 09:00:00
2020-02-29 09:15:00
2020-03-15 15:00:00
2020-07-31 14:00:00
```